# How to save CSE Excel formula in plain CSV format?

Tags: excel, csv, formula

I would like to form CSV excel file in my program. Some cells contains CSE (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formulas (array formulas).

This does not work:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000)=0; ""; 1/COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000)))
```

This does not work too:

```
{=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000)=0; ""; 1/COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000)))}
```

This formula makes distinct count on cells array...

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your array formulas to normal formulas by using instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B4:B1000<>"")/COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000&""))
```

A general technique to do this is to wrap functions with array arguments in `MMULT(...;1)`:

```
=SUM(IF(MMULT(COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000);1)=0; ""; 1/MMULT(COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000);1)))
```

**Example**

When saving the CSV file, make sure to display formulas by pressing Ctrl+` [back-quote] which is a shortcut for *Excel Options > Advanced > Show Formulas in cells instead of their calculated result.*

[image]

The setup above saves in CSV format as below.

```
Sheet1;
;"=SUMPRODUCT((B4:B1000<>"""")/COUNTIF(B4:B1000;B4:B1000&""""))"
;Values
;1
;2
;
;3
;1
;a
;a
```

You can check this by copying the contents of the text file to cell A1 in a new sheet and choosing *Data > Text To Columns > Delimited > Delimiter: Semicolon*.

I'm assuming Decimal Separator:`,` Thousands Separator:`.` (in *Excel Options> Advanced*).

Comment: I've added an example which works ok on my set up. Note that in the csv file the formula is enclosed in quotes (which are the default text qualifier) because the same delimiter is used for cells and formula arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the brackets themselves, then you can run the following macro, then save the file as CSV. You can do this in addition to the [Ctrl + `] method lori_m mentions.

```
Option Explicit


Sub AddBrackets()

Dim cell As Range

With Sheet1
    For Each cell In UsedRange
        If cell.HasArray Then
            cell.Value = "{" & cell.FormulaLocal & "}"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```