# Excel Filter Where Columns are different

Tags: excel, filter

I have two columns in an excel worksheet. I want to filter where the two columns are different. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or even more simply put this in the third column

```
=A1=B1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a calculated column like =A2=B2 and filter for FALSE on that column.

Here's an alternative that only requires formatting the differences...

1) Select the two columns you want to compare and press `[Ctrl+\]` (or *goto special|row differences*). If you want to remove the column heading from the selection press `[Ctrl+Shift+\]` (or *goto special|column differences*). See example below

[image]
[image]

2) Format the selected cells with a font color then right-click the selected cell and choose *Filter > Filter by selected cell's font color*:

[image]

Comment: great job on this very high quality answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/11755272/117700

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a third column

```
   =if(A1=B1,1,0)
```

filter where that thridcolumn=0